# Possible to automatically add elements to collection?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am new at Entity Framework (and stack overflow - first question!):

Right now I got the following entities in my db:

Blog:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }

public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

Post:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }

public int BlogId { get; set; }

[Required]
[ForeignKey("BlogId")]
public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
```

Currently whenever I add a post I manually add it to the Collection of the corresponding blog.
I Wonder if it's possible to automatically add them to the Collection as I add the posts that are referencing the corresponding blog?

Comment: Remove the `Attribute` suffix, C# automatically puts that.

Comment: @HighCore
Do you mean the [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]?

Comment: yep, leave it `[DataBaseGenerated(...)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use your entity class to create the entity rather than `new`, ie:

```
Posts.Add(Post.Create());
```

instead of

```
Posts.Add(new Blog());
```

but if you MUST pass arguments, you will need to do

```
Post p = Post.Create();
p.BlogId = 1234;
p.SomeString = "Test";
p.SomeDate = DateTme.Now;

Posts.Add(p);
```

and as always, call `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: I see - however I need to pass some arguments to the constructor - how do I do that The Create method doesn't accept any arguments.

Comment: you need to use the default constructor with create, but should be able to use `Post.Create() { BlogId = 1234; BlogTitle = "Something" };` to mimic anything you would need to pass to the CTOR

Comment: But will the constructor method still run then?
I'm setting the date of the post in the constructor (automatically sets to now)

Comment: @bizzehdee You can only use the object initializer syntax in conjunction with constructors. It doesn't work on methods.

Comment: @Zebedee The parameter-less constructor should, yes.